# Swing button not being added

Tags: swing

I am a newbie to SWING. 
I have written a code for frame having a button when clicked a new frame opens. But i don't know whats wrong with the code that the new frame/window is not containing the button i have added in code.

```
setTitle("Frame1");
    setSize(250, 250);
    setDefaultCloseOperation(1);
    setVisible(true);

    JPanel panel1= new JPanel();
    getContentPane().add(panel1);
    JButton button1= new JButton();
    button1.setText("Click to open new window");
    button1.setBounds(20, 15, 14, 18);
    button1.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
            JFrame newFrame= new JFrame();
            newFrame.setBounds(150, 150, 150, 150);
            newFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(1);
            newFrame.setTitle("New Frame");
            newFrame.setVisible(true);
            JPanel panel2= new JPanel();
            getContentPane().add(panel2);
            JButton button2= new JButton();
            button2.setText("QUIT");
            button2.setBounds(10, 5, 4, 8);
            panel2.add(button2);
            button2.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                    System.exit(0);

                }
            });

        }
    });     
    panel1.add(button1);}
```

Please help!

Comment: You are invoking getContentPane() inside the actionListener. My guess would be that this is the contentPane of the root window (not the one you opened). Try newFrame.getContentPane()

Answer (score 0):

You add `JButton button1` to `JPanel panel1` but you don't add the `JPanel pane1` to the `JFrame` itself.

You need to add the `JPanel panel1` to the `JFrame`

```
add(panel1);
```

Comment: getContentPane().add(panel1); is doing the same thing as add(panel1)

Comment: Ohh sorry I didn't see that line.